# Link folder into another folder

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

in Linux, is it possible to make the system pretend a folders content is inside another folder.

So basicly:

```
~/scripts/hello # says hello world on console
ln ~/scripts/ ~/.local/bin
hello
>hello world
```

with .local/bin not being empty

Is there a way to achive this? to have a local folder basically link to another while still containing files itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for *bind mounts*.

```
mount --bind ~/scripts ~/.local/bin
```

You'll need root privileges to execute it. It also doesn't persist between reboots unless you add an appropriate `fstab` entry:

```
/home/user/scripts /home/user/.local/bin none bind
```